# Position text with background exactly in corner of matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to label my plots alphabetically in a multi-axes plot. With `ax.text` and manual coordinates, I can achieve that on a single figure:

```
ax.text(0.01, 0.96, 
    'A', transform=ax.transAxes, fontweight='bold', va='top', ha='left',
    backgroundcolor='k', color='white')
```

[image: Working example]

I want the black box to match the upper left corner exactly. Applying the above code on another figure does not work:

[image: Not working example]

**Is there a way to match the black box of the text background with the axis corner exactly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a consistent way that works regardless of the figure size or arangement of axes. For `ax` being an `AxesSubplot` object use:

```
ax.annotate(
    'A', 
    (0, 1),
    xytext=(4, -4),
    xycoords='axes fraction',
    textcoords='offset points',
    fontweight='bold',
    color='white',
    backgroundcolor='k',
    ha='left', va='top')
```

Note that my "global" matplotlib fontsize is set to 8. If you use another fontsize you probably have to change the `xytext` values.

Comment: how to stack on top another?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: How to place two annotations on top of each other with some gap in between?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. Please open a new question on stackoverflow with a visual example and link it here